# How could I fix this conceptual search error?

Tags: curl, ibm-cloud, concept-insights

I was trying to use conceptual search in Concept Insights, but this error came up:

> Error response:
>   {"code": 500, "message": "Forwarding error"}

I have two documents in test1 corpus.

Execution code:

```
curl -u "user id":"Password" "https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/conceptinsights/api/v2/corpora/accountid/test1/related_concepts?limit=1"
```

Comment: A quick note: The Concept Insights service will be deprecated on August 12, 2016, after which no new instances of the service can be created. For more info, see: https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/concept-insights/

Comment: You can use the Concept function in the Alchemy API service as a replacement for most Concept Insights use cases. Therefore, it is encouraged that you migrate to the AlchemyAPI service. See: https://console.ng.bluemix.net/catalog/services/alchemyapi/